# Heroku Deployment Failure from Travis CI

Tags: node.js, api, heroku, authorization, travis-ci

My app deployment to Heroku stopped working two days ago, (January 14th). I received the error:

> API request failed. Message: Invalid credentials provided.

This app has been online for nearly a year and I’ve never had issues with a deployment before. I use GitHub for version control. Testing and deployment to Heroku are automatically performed by Travis CI when any updates are pushed to the Master branch.

Here’s a link to the latest broken build: https://travis-ci.org/drichards211/revuer/builds/637772527

```sh
221 The command “npm test” exited with 0.
222 store build cache
223 nothing changed
224
225 rvm $(travis_internal_ruby) --fuzzy do ruby -S gem install dpl
226 Successfully installed dpl-1.10.14
227 1 gem installed
228
229 Installing deploy dependencies
230 Successfully installed multipart-post-2.1.1
231 Successfully installed faraday-1.0.0
232 Successfully installed rendezvous-0.1.3
233 Successfully installed netrc-0.11.0
234 Successfully installed dpl-heroku-1.10.14
235 5 gems installed
236
237 API request failed.
238 Message: Invalid credentials provided.
239 Reference:
240 Preparing deploy
241
242 failed to deploy
```

Nothing has changed on my end. I’ve since updated all Node dependencies as a broad-spectrum inoculant, but the problem appears after the tests successfully complete and deployment is attempted by Travis. This appears to be a credentials handshake issue between Travis CI and Heroku.

I attempted opening a ticket with Heroku, but they won’t accept tickets on free applications. I wrote a similar message on the Travis Community Forums; one of their developers got back to me right away, but they haven't been able to find anything wrong, yet.

I've also updated my Heroku API token and encrypted and updated that value with Travis CI. No change.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

24 hours later I re-encrypted the Heroku API token *again* and updated the value with Travis CI. This time it worked; a successful deployment. There's no indication as to the cause of the initial problem or as to why it's working now. A delicious mystery.